# How to get access token for authenticated user to make an authorized resource api call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, oauth-2.0, claims-based-identity

I have simple MVC 5 Owin project that uses a Auth server for authentication to request a token. When a user has logged in, how can I get the user's token to make other protected requests on the API? Do I store it as a claim of the currently logged ClaimsIdentity?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static string _strSISApiUrl = "YourAPIURL";

  public static string GetUserAuthenticationToken(string strUserID, string strPwd)

  {
    #if(SISAVILABLE)

    List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> objKeyValuePair= new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
                objKeyValuePair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("username",strUserID));
                objKeyValuePair.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("password",strPwd));
                string jSONResult = RestHttpClient.HttpPost(_strSISApiUrl + "login", objKeyValuePair);
                return jSONResult;
            #else
                return "{auth_token:'your api token'}";
            #endif
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I am looking for a way to get the token after login, to make other protected requests. The first part is first, I am able to call the Auth Server to login and get a valid token. However, to make other calls to protected resources, I need to pass the bearer token as an Authorization Header, now where is the appropriate  place to retrieve this value?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Users
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 3)]
   //[Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
  //  [Display(Name = "Password")]
    private string _AuthenticatedToken ;
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string val { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string AuthenticatedToken {
        get {
                return _AuthenticatedToken;
            }
    }
    public bool AuthenticateUser() 
    {
        SISInterfaceBus objSISInterfaceBus = new SISInterfaceBus();
        SISValidateUserResultSet objSISValidateUserResultSet = objSISInterfaceBus.ValidateLogin(this.UserName,this.Password);
        _AuthenticatedToken = objSISValidateUserResultSet.SISAuthToken;
        return objSISValidateUserResultSet.IsValidUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: use this class to retrieve login user's authentication token in your main page. llike:- Users objUser =(Users ) Session["USER"]; CommonValue objCommonValues = new CommonValue();
                model.WorkingSet = objCommonValues.AvailableWorkingSets(objUser);